# python: how to wait in a for loop for user inputs in popup windows

Tags: python, tkinter, user-input, wait

I wanted to login to a webpage three times as follows.

1. Push the "button1"
2. Login window pops up then enter ID & PW and push the "Enter" button
3. do something
4. repeat #2 & 3 three times.

I am stuck at making the code wait until a user pushes the "Enter" button.

I'm pretty new to python. Any comments will be greatly helpful.

[image: Main window]
[image: popup login window]

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk  
import time

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x500')


# functions ----------------------------------
def popup():
    global pop
    pop= Toplevel(root)
    pop.title('Login')
    pop.geometry('450x100')
  
    global me
    fr1=Frame(pop)
    fr1.pack(pady=5)
    
    lbl1=Label(fr1, text='ID :', font=20)
    lbl1.grid(row=1, column=1,pady=7)
    e1 = Entry(fr1, width=15,font=(25))
    e1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    
    lbl2=Label(fr1, text='PW :', font=20)
    lbl2.grid(row=2, column=1)
    e2 = Entry(fr1, width=15,font=(25))
    e2.grid(row=2, column=2)
    
    btn1 = Button(fr1, text='Enter',width=10, font=20)
    btn1.grid(row=1, column=3, rowspan=2, sticky=N+E+W+S, padx=10, pady=10) 


def  button_():      
    for i in [1,2,3]: 
        popup() 
        

bt1=Button(root, text='button1', command=button_)
bt1.pack(pady=10)


root.mainloop()
```

==================================================

Thanks to you all. I finally got what I wanted.
I take the Sujay logic and hope this help for those who may have the same problem.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk  
import time


# functions ----------------------------------

# 0 I don't understand this part but it still works without this.
# Force you to pass in the master argument when creating widgets:
# tk._support_default_root = False
#----------------------------------------------------------------

def popup():
    global pop   
    pop = tk.Tk()       # 1. <-- pop= Toplevel(root)
    pop.title('Login')
    pop.geometry('450x100')

    fr1=Frame(pop)
    fr1.pack(pady=5)
    
    lbl1=Label(fr1, text='ID :', font=20)
    lbl1.grid(row=1, column=1,pady=7)
    e1 = Entry(fr1, width=15,font=(25))
    e1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    
    lbl2=Label(fr1, text='PW :', font=20)
    lbl2.grid(row=2, column=1)
    e2 = Entry(fr1, width=15,font=(25))
    e2.grid(row=2, column=2)
    
    btn1 = Button(fr1, text='Enter',width=10, font=20)
    btn1.grid(row=1, column=3, rowspan=2, sticky=N+E+W+S, padx=10, pady=10) 
    

    # 2.---------------------------------------------
    # Wait until there is only 1 window left open
    pop.mainloop(1)
    #---------------------------------------------
    
def  button_():
    for i in range(3):
        popup()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x500')

bt1=tk.Button(root, text='button1', command=button_)
bt1.pack(pady=10)



# Wait until all windows have been closed
root.mainloop()
```

As you can see, code #1, #2 are what solve my problem.
but I still don't understand why #1 works and what does #0 means.

Comment: Does there `button_()` something happen after enter ? You could restructure your code for this, if there is nothing complex happening.

Comment: Add `pop.grab_set()` and `pop.wait_window()` at the end of `popup()`.  Also you need to close the popup when the `Enter` button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is check if the popup window has been opened 3 times.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk  
import time

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x500')


# functions ----------------------------------
def popup():
    global pop
    pop= Toplevel(root)
    pop.focus_force()
    pop.grab_set()
    pop.title('Login')
    pop.geometry('450x100')
  
    global me
    fr1=Frame(pop)
    fr1.pack(pady=5)
    
    lbl1=Label(fr1, text='ID :', font=20)
    lbl1.grid(row=1, column=1,pady=7)
    e1 = Entry(fr1, width=15,font=(25))
    e1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    
    lbl2=Label(fr1, text='PW :', font=20)
    lbl2.grid(row=2, column=1)
    e2 = Entry(fr1, width=15,font=(25))
    e2.grid(row=2, column=2)
    
    btn1 = Button(fr1, text='Enter',command=button_,width=10, font=20)
    btn1.grid(row=1, column=3, rowspan=2, sticky=N+E+W+S, padx=10, pady=10) 

done=1
def  button_():      
    global done
    if done==3:
        pop.destroy()
    else: 
        done+=1
        pop.destroy()
        popup()
        

bt1=Button(root, text='button1', command=popup)
bt1.pack(pady=10)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Nice Program :)

Comment: Did it solve the problem

Comment: No. Please try your code before posting it as answer, except you know it works.

Comment: Did you test your code? Exception raised when `Enter` button is clicked.

Comment: That is because he didnt assign a command for Enter. But it did what the question was asked

Comment: What was the exception

Comment: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'done' referenced before assignment`. It is because you forget to declare `done` as global inside `button_()`.  Also your logic will show the popup four times, not three.

Comment: Although your updated code fixed the exception, but does not fulfil OP requirement *"wait until a user pushes the "Enter" button"*.  The `button1` is still clickable when the popup is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk  
import time

# Force you to pass in the master argument when creating widgets:
tk._support_default_root = False

def popup():
    global pop_window
    pop_window = tk.Tk()
    pop_window.geometry("200x100")

    entry = tk.Entry(pop_window)
    entry.pack()
    
    button = tk.Button(pop_window, text="Enter", command=pop_window.destroy)
    button.pack()

    # Wait until there is only 1 window left open
    pop_window.mainloop(1)

def button_():
    global done
    if done:
        done = False
        for i in range(3):
            popup()
        done = True

done = True

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")

button = tk.Button(root, text="Click me", command=button_)
button.pack()

# Close the program when the main window is destroyed:
# Instead here you can call a function that sets `done` to `True`,
# Closes the main window as well as the `pop_window` if it exists
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", exit)

# Wait until all windows have been closed
root.mainloop()
```

It uses multiple instances of `Tk()` and waits until there is only 1 window left open before continuing with the `for` loop. That is done using: `pop_window.mainloop(1)`

It uses multiple instances of `Tk()` so you need to be careful when creating `StringVar`/`IntVar`/.../`PhotoImage`s. As long as you always pass in the `master` argument when creating those variables, you shouldn't encounter any problems.

Comment: There are safe ways to achive this. Do you really think this is appropriated?

Comment: @Atlas435 I think this is the easiest way of doing it. Also I have a comment telling OP to always pass in the `master` argument.

Comment: @Atlas435 I edited it (added `tk._support_default_root = False`) to force the user to always pass in the `master` argument when creating tkinter widgets/variables so it really shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: I dont think this solves all the problems that can be caused by doing so. The event loop could still struggle and some features propbably wont work properly.

Comment: @Atlas435 I don't see any problems, except that you can press the (main window) button while the other windows are running but a simple global variable will fix the problem. Also because of the `tk._support_default_root = False`, it will raise an error when you create a tkinter variable without passing the `master` argument.

Comment: Just for instance, close your root window while a pop_up is open. Is this the designed way it should work? If this would be a real thing it can mean trouble.

Comment: @Atlas435 Fair point. I updated my answer (just added a call to `exit()` when the user closes the main window)

Comment: Try to bind a `'<Destroy>'` event to the root. You cant thinking this through. Anyway, have a good day.

Comment: Thanks you all. all comments are really helpful!!